# Consuming webservices in Jaspersoft Studio behind firewall

Tags: web-services, jasper-reports, ssl-certificate, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I am Working on Jaspersoft Studio. I am trying to consume a webservice from Jasper Studio. I am working behind a corporate firewall. The webservice that I am trying to consume is https. I am getting SSL certificate error. Can anyone please suggest me how to ignore the SSL certification and consume the https webservice in Jaspersoft Studio.

I am using

- JasperReports Server CP 5.1.0
- Jaspersoft studio 6.5.1

Answer (score 0):

You can't just ignore the SSL certificate if you want to connect to a resource that requires SSL connection. To make it working, you have to import a valid certificate using keytool command into Jaspersoft Studio. Import security certificate at below location:

`Jaspersoft Studio Professional-x.x.x root, \final\features\jre.win32.win32.x86_64.feature_1.8.0.u74\jre\lib\security`